# Change JSON structure using jq

Tags: json, jq

Hi stackoverflow community. I hope somebody can help me out with some JSON structuring problem. I'm very new to jq, so this problem is a very though one for me...

I have a JSON with the following structure

```
{
  "a": {
    "b": {
      "1": {
        "anyKey1": {
          "value": {
            "fontFamily": "value1",
            "fontWeight": "value2",
            "lineHeight": "value3",
            "fontSize": "value4",
            "letterSpacing": "value5",
            "textDecoration": "value6",
            "textCase": "value7"
          },
          "type": "typography"
        }
      }
    },
    "anyKey2": {
      "value": {
        "fontFamily": "value1",
        "fontWeight": "value2",
        "lineHeight": "value3",
        "fontSize": "value4",
        "letterSpacing": "value5",
        "textDecoration": "value6",
        "textCase": "value7"
      },
      "type": "typography"
    }
  }
}
```

I need to change it to the following structure wherever in a JSON the above structure is appearing:

```
{
  "a": {
    "b": {
      "1": {
        "anyKey1": {
          "fontFamily": {
            "value": "value1",
            "type": "typography"
          },
          "fontWeight": {
            "value": "value2",
            "type": "typography"
          },
          "lineHeight": {
            "value": "value3",
            "type": "typography"
          },
          "fontSize": {
            "value": "value4",
            "type": "typography"
          },
          "letterSpacing": {
            "value": "value5",
            "type": "typography"
          },
          "textDecoration": {
            "value": "value6",
            "type": "typography"
          },
          "textCase": {
            "value": "value7",
            "type": "typography"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "anyKey2": {
      "fontFamily": {
        "value": "value1",
        "type": "typography"
      },
      "fontWeight": {
        "value": "value2",
        "type": "typography"
      },
      "lineHeight": {
        "value": "value3",
        "type": "typography"
      },
      "fontSize": {
        "value": "value4",
        "type": "typography"
      },
      "letterSpacing": {
        "value": "value5",
        "type": "typography"
      },
      "textDecoration": {
        "value": "value6",
        "type": "typography"
      },
      "textCase": {
        "value": "value7",
        "type": "typography"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The rest of the JSON should keep unmodified. I hope some jq expert can help me out here. :)

PS: Thanks to pmf for the given answer, it was already very helpful to understand the way jq works. But I need it more dynamic, because I don't now always the naming of the keys. The only keys I always know is value and type. Therefore I also edited my question a little bit.
I tried myself already a lot to get my needed result, but I couldn't succeed till now. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `walk` to recursively visit each subitem. With each visit, `select` only those `objects` that have fields called `value` and `type` which are of `type` `"object"` and `"string"`, respectively. Update (`|=`) these objects by first storing their `.type` field in a variable `$type`. Then, consider the `.value` field, and modify each of its fields by updating (`|=`) them to an object using their original value `.` and the previously stored `$type` variable.

```bash
walk(
  (objects | select([.value, .type | type] == ["object","string"])) |=
  (.type as $type | .value | with_entries(.value |= {value: ., $type}))
)
```

```json
{
  "a": {
    "b": {
      "1": {
        "anyKey1": {
          "fontFamily": {
            "value": "value1",
            "type": "typography"
          },
          "fontWeight": {
            "value": "value2",
            "type": "typography"
          },
          "lineHeight": {
            "value": "value3",
            "type": "typography"
          },
          "fontSize": {
            "value": "value4",
            "type": "typography"
          },
          "letterSpacing": {
            "value": "value5",
            "type": "typography"
          },
          "textDecoration": {
            "value": "value6",
            "type": "typography"
          },
          "textCase": {
            "value": "value7",
            "type": "typography"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "anyKey2": {
      "fontFamily": {
        "value": "value1",
        "type": "typography"
      },
      "fontWeight": {
        "value": "value2",
        "type": "typography"
      },
      "lineHeight": {
        "value": "value3",
        "type": "typography"
      },
      "fontSize": {
        "value": "value4",
        "type": "typography"
      },
      "letterSpacing": {
        "value": "value5",
        "type": "typography"
      },
      "textDecoration": {
        "value": "value6",
        "type": "typography"
      },
      "textCase": {
        "value": "value7",
        "type": "typography"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/ellJioMljD4)

Comment: Cool thanks! That works already really amazing. But I would need a few more adjustments.

I have also the case, that sometimes the value is a string, so unfortunately I get this error for my final JSON file:


`jq: error (at <stdin>:1120): string ("Inter") has no keys
exit status 5`
And is it possible to make it more dynamic, because I have not only typography as key, there are many others and the nesting is also not always the same depth.

Comment: @phil88 Do you mean the outer `.typography` or the inner `"type": "typography"`? The latter is being fetched dynamically into the `$type` variable. For the former just replace it with yet another iterator `[]` to process all its siblings as well. Regarding the string issue, you would need to include it into your example, so that it's clear where and how it occurs, as well as how the output should look like in those cases.

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply. Exactly I meant the outer `.typography`. Then I will just replace it with another `[]`.
For the string issue I extended my question post with an example.

Comment: @phil88 Regarding the error: Could you please update your question, so that I can adapt my answer to it? Generally speaking, `.typography[][][]` (or `.[][][][]`) will go **exactly 4** levels deep. If the structure worked upon is located higher or lower, it won't be caught and/or could lead to undesired behaviour, or errors even. Therefore, you may want to have more criteria where to find the structures in question. For instance, you could find any (nested) object having a field called `type` using `.. | objects | select(has("type"))`, and work from there.

Comment: The levels of depth are always different. And it's not only the name typography, it can also be any other name. So in general as I updated it in my question I need to find anywhere in the JSON the key pair "value" and "type" as siblings where "value" is an object and need it to convert into the structure I mentioned in my question.

Comment: Thanks again for your hint, I have it now like that `(.. | objects | select(has("type"))) |= (.type as $type | .value | with_entries(.value |= {value: ., $type}))` But I get this error `jq: error (at <stdin>:1156): string ("Inter") has no keys`. So I guess I need somehow to exclude all `value` keys, where the value of it is a string. I tried to include something like `.value | type | . != "string"`. But I don't now in which position I need to add it.

Comment: @phil88 `has("type")` was meant to be an example, not the suolution. I will have a look at your update when I am back home.

Comment: Oops... :D My bad. Ok sure, thanks a lot.

Comment: @phil88 Here's my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you so much! It works absolutely perfect.